# What is the "Untrustworthy" tag on bitcointalk?

Tags: forum, bitcointalk

I just saw [some people](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=24749) that were once labeled "Scammers" are now labeled "Untrustworthy" instead. Does anyone retain scammer tags, or was this a rename? Where was this discussed/announced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People still have scammer tags.

"Untrustworthy" is technically different than the scammer tag - the latter is a forum position, which appears in a certain place and has a specific icon. In Matthew's case it is just a custom title, usually reserved for VIP donators who can write there whatever they want.

I suppose Matthew's tag was commuted as part of his rehabilitation process.